# How to do/escape shoulder strikes to the body with your back against the cage?

Tags: ufc-undisputed-2010

How to do/escape shoulder strikes to the body with your back against the cage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I struggle with this situation too, but here is the basic plan I try to use:

1. Blocking to wear them out (energy)
2. Advance in to a Clinch (tricky, and usually involves switching between advancing and blocking a couple times to get it right)
3. Once I get double underhooks, I go straight for the double leg take down

Again, my success rate is not high...

I've heard people say you can go counter into muay tai, but I can't pull it off.